# I can't evolve Beldum

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I'm playing Alpha Sapphire and I did the auto leveling loop on Steven's Beldum and now its level is 52, but it hasn't evolved yet.
What should I do? I've already tried a random trainer battle.

Comment: Auto leveling loop? Just a note: if it's holding an Everstone it will never evolve.

Comment: Have you tried with Magikarp?

Answer (score 3):

Beldum normally evolves at level 20, so you're missing something.

If with "*auto leveling loop*" you mean that you left Beldum at the Daycare and you are riding the bike in loop in order to make it earn easy experience, then you'll need to raise another level by battling or give him a Rare Candy to trigger the evolution process.

And the Pokemon doesn't have to hold the Everstone, of course.